# Error 'System.Diagnostics.Process' does not contain a definition for 'GetProcesses' in visual studio 2008 c#

Tags: c#, compact-framework

How to kill process in visual studio 2008 c#? I tried the below code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace GR
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Login loginform;
    public EntryForm entryform;

    public Form1()
    {
        //userName = "";
        InitializeComponent();
        //CheckForInternetConnection();

        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {

            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.StartsWith("Bin_"))
            {
                clsProcess.Kill();
            }
        }
        loginform=new Login();

        entryform = new EntryForm();
        Controls.Add(loginform);
        Controls.Add(entryform);

        loginform.Show();
        entryform.Hide();

        loginform.entryForm = entryform;
        entryform.loginForm = loginform;

    }
  } 
}
```

I am getting this error

> 'System.Diagnostics.Process' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetProcesses'.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you sure? What is your .NET version?

Comment: With the information present here, this is unreproducible since GetProcesses is very much present in Process. Can you ensure you don't have any funky unicode-characters present in the name or something like that? Can you place the cursor inside Process and hit F12 and tell us where it takes you?

Comment: Can you add your full code.  The problem may be elsewhere.  Also, ensure that you are referencing the correct DLL library.

Comment: Or, rather than full code, please show us a *complete* and *small* example that correctly reproduces your problem. The process of producing such a sample quite often leads to a solution.

Comment: Are you targeting .Net 1.0/1.1?

Comment: .NET Compact, probably, VS2008 was the last version that still supported it.  Yes, it doesn't have a GetProcesses() method, you'll have to learn to live without it :)

Comment: Another tip - stick around after you ask a question so that you are able to respond to comments.

Comment: @SonerGönül i am using .Net Compact Framework Version 3.5

Comment: @HansPassant , can you give me any idea to kill the process in case of  any running application?

Comment: @Kami , i have added my full code , please look into that.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen when i hit F12 i can see some code under public class Process : Component
    { , but i dont see anything like getprocess()

Comment: Is the code decompiled from assembly or do you have that class as part of your source code?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i don't have any class in my source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ompact Framework doesn't support it, which is why you get the error.  The fallback is to use the Toolhelp APIs, like the SDF does. Take a look at the `ProcessEntry` [class in the SDF](https://opennetcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OpenNETCF/OpenNETCF/ToolHelp/ProcessEntry.cs).  Specifically the `GetProcesses()` method and the subsequent `Kill()` method.